# How to determine whether domain is an open or a closed region (or both open and closed)?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

Right now I am studying Partial Derivative in my university, but I am confused in its basic topic; Multi-variable Functions

More specifically, I am having difficulty in understanding open or closed domain regions in XY Plane and whether they are bounded or not?

For Example:

---

### **Question**

Given that $f(x, y)=x^2 - y^2$

**(a)** Find the function's domain
**(b)** Find the function's range
**(c)** Describe function's level curves
**(d)** Find the boundary of the function’s domain
**(e)** Determine if the domain is an open region, a closed region, or neither
**(f)** Decide if the domain is bounded or unbounded

---

---

### **Solution**

**(a)** Domain: Entire XY Plane
**(b)** Range: $(-\infty, \infty)$
**(c)** Level Curves: $x^2-y^2=c$
**(d)** Since the domain is entire plane, there is no boundary
**(e)** Following is my understanding of open and closed domain in XY Plane:

- A domain (denoted by region R) is said to be ***closed*** **if the region R contains *all* boundary points**
- If the **region R does not contain *any* boundary points**, then the Domain is said to be ***open***
- If the **region R contains *some but not all* of the boundary points**, then the Domain is said to be ***both open and closed***

The answer in book is: **both open and closed**, but how can we even say that if there is no boundary as answered in part (d)?

**(f)** Following is my understanding of bounded and unbounded domains:

- If the boundary points form a closed loop, then the domain is said to be bounded, otherwise they are considered unbounded.

OR

- ***Books Definition***: A region in the plane is bounded if it lies inside a disk of finite radius. A region is unbounded if it is not bounded.

The answer of this part in book is: ***Unbounded***, and this is because I think (please correct me if I am wrong), since there is no boundary, the region can not be bounded, so by default, the region is unbounded.

Comment: If the region contains some but not all of its boundary points then it is *not open* (it contains some of its boundary points) and is *not closed* (it does not contain all of its boundary points). Exactly the opposite of your understanding.

Comment: "Boundary" and "bounded" are unrelated for the sake of these questions. Also, the boundary of a bounded region need not be a loop, and it may have more than one component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression "there is no boundary" must be read as "the boundary is empty".

---

For region $R$ there is always a set $\partial R$ of boundary points. We have $x\in\partial R$ if every neighborhood of $x$ has a non-empty intersection with $R$ and has a not empty intersection with $R^c=\mathbb R^2\setminus R$.

$R$ is open if it contains none of these boundary points, i.e. if $R\cap\partial R=\varnothing$.

$R$ is closed if it contains all of these boundary points, i.e. if $\partial R\subseteq R$.

In your example $R=\mathbb R^2$ so that $\partial R=\varnothing$. Consequently $R\cap\partial R=\varnothing$ as well as $\partial R\subseteq R$.

So $R$ is open and closed.

There is no $r\in\mathbb R$ such that $R=\mathbb R\subseteq\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq r^2\}$. This justifies the statement that $R$ is unbounded.

Comment: OK, so I am not well versed in set notation, so I am writing whatever I understood in simple words. I would be really grateful if you can correct any misconceptions I have:


For every region $R$ there will always be a set of boundary points $\partial R$.


If the intersection of $R$ and $\partial R$ is $\varnothing$, then the region is open.


If the $\partial R$ is an improper subset of $R$, then the region is closed.


If both of the above conditions are true then the region said to be both open and closed

Comment: If you can elaborate your second sentence: "We have $x\in\partial R$ if...", and your last sentence: "There is no $r\in\mathbb R$ such that...", I would be really grateful.

Comment: Do you agree that no real number $r$ exists such that every element of $\mathbb R$ is element of the disk that has the origin as center and has $r$ as radius? That's what I am saying there. The observation that no such real number exists is the same as the observation that $\mathbb R$ is not a bounded set. Secondly: do you know what a neighborhood is in this context? Your interpretations mentioned in your comment are correct except that you better leave out the (irrelevant) term "improper". Just "subset" is enough.

Comment: No, I don't know what does neighborhood mean in the current context. BTW, Above explanation answered all of my initial concerns so I have marked the question answered.

Comment: Here a "neighborhoodless" description of boundary points of $R$, i.e. elements of $\partial R$: an element $\langle x,y\rangle$ will be a boundary point of $R$ if every disk that has this element as origin will have a non-empty intersection with $R$ and also with the complement of $R$.